# solr sub facet sort not working with query for derived field

Tags: solr

I need get 2 facet, if possible i can divide 2 facet values and get a derived field and sort it,

Simple Working Example for Comparision:

```
 const jsonFacet = { // json facet for counts
    users: {
      type: 'terms',
      field: 'job_type_id',
      limit: 30,
      sort: 'div(expected/current)',
      facet: {
        expected: 'sum(expected_salary)',
        current: 'sum(current_salary)',
      },
    },
  };
```

Output of the working example

```
facets: {
    count: 857,
      users: {
      buckets: [
        {
          val: 1737,
          count: 623,
          expected: 10449,
          current: 10449,
        },
        {
          val: 3387,
          count: 149,
          expected: 10449,
          current: 10449,
        },
        {
          val: 3189,
          count: 85,
          expected: 10449,
          current: 10449,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

My Example - Which is not working, when i add query for the facet, I can't use or I'm not able to find any docs `div()`

```
 const jsonFacet = { // json facet for counts
        users: {
          type: 'terms',
          field: 'job_type_id',
          limit: 30,
          sort: 'div(expected.count,current.count)', // issues here
          facet: {
            expected: {
              query: 'state_id:(4 5 8 9 10)',
            },
            current: {
              query: 'state_id:(2 3 4 5 8 9)',
            }
          },
        },
      };
```

Output of the query with issue, if I won't add `sort` then  I'll get below result. If i enable sort(I don't get docs anywhere, tried in my own way) then i get `error":{"trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n`

```
facets: {
    count: 857,
      users: {
      buckets: [
        {
          val: 1737,
          count: 623,
          shortlist_ratio_num: {
            count: 337
          },
          shortlist_ratio_den: {
            count: 452
          }
        },
        {
          val: 3387,
          count: 149,
          shortlist_ratio_num: {
            count: 31
          },
          shortlist_ratio_den: {
            count: 56
          }
        },
        {
          val: 3189,
          count: 85,
          shortlist_ratio_num: {
            count: 29
          },
          shortlist_ratio_den: {
            count: 56
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```